# git rebase: How to add files by their index in the list

Tags: git, addition, rebase

I am trying to `git rebase` branch A on branch B and there are some conflicts.

The `git status`, shows the list of files that are in conflict.

```
# Changes not staged for commit:
#   (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
#   (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)

    modified: \very_long_path\file1.py
    modified: \very_long_path\file2.py
```

My workflow is to resolve the files one by one and use `git add filename` to approve. Is there is a way in git to refer to a file by their position in the list?  `git add FILE~1` , as opposed to `git add \very_long_path\file1.py`

Comment: There is `git add --interactive`, but I hate it, I just use mouse cut-and-paste for file names for simple cases, and `git status --short > /tmp/master-list` when it's very long. I can then edit `/tmp/master-list`, extract just the right names, discard the status characters at the front, and run `xargs /tmp/master-list | git add` or similar to add them.

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no such command. You have to call `git add path/to/file` for the files you want to add.

If the path is not *unmerged*, `git add --patch` could help but it too doesn't provide a way to select "the second file", you can only stage some changes while you don't stage others.